Inequality with two concave functions
is this inequality holds true
$[\frac{\frac{f_2(x_0,y_0)}{y_0}}{\frac{f_2(x,y)}{y}}-\frac{f_1(x_0,y_0)}{f_1(x,y_0)}]\times [\frac{f_1(x,y_0)}{f_1(x_0,y_0)}-\frac{f_2(x,y)}{f_2(x_0,y_0)}]\leq 0 \; \forall \, x,y\geq 0$
with $f_i$ are concave, increasing with respect to $x$ and $y$ and $f_i(0,y)=f_i(x,0)=0, i=1,2$, may be Jensen's reverse inequality can help. Thank you for your help.

Do you mean $\forall x, y, x_0, y_0 \ge 0$?
